# Android: How to write newline in CSV file?

Tags: java, android, csv

I am trying to organize my data in .CSV file.I want to put my data in a particular row so i tried putting "\n" but it is not working.Please help me in putting data to a particular row.Thank you in advance..

```
public void writeData(String data,String strFilePath)
        {

            PrintWriter csvWriter;
            try
            {

                File file = new File(strFilePath);
                if(!file.exists()){
                    file = new File(strFilePath);
                }
                csvWriter = new  PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));


                csvWriter.print(data+","+"hello");
                csvWriter.append('\n');
                csvWriter.print("world");


                csvWriter.close();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? What exactly do you see? Being specific when asking questions will give you the answers you need.

Comment: For example if "first,second\nthird" is added into csv, only "first" and "second" is visible..we cannot view "third" in csv file.I hope this is the problem with android editors.suppose if I transfer my .csv into windows PC, even "third" is visible in new row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You code looks good, and I am sure the newline is written correctly to the file. The only reason that I can think of is that you opened the file with an editor that does not treat `\n` as a line separator, it treats `\r\n` pair as a line separator(like Notepad on Windows).

So you can either write the newline with `write.print("\r\n")`, or simply open the file with some other editors like `vim`. No matter what editor you use to open the file, the newline character is there.

Comment: I am trying to open with excel..its not working as u said...please guide me through good editors which can show up "\n"

Comment: Have you tried opening the file from Excel by `File -> Import -> CSV File`. You should not directly open the file with Excel, which may not be able to detect that it is a CSV file. For editors, `notepad++`, or commercial ones like `EditPlus` or `UltraEdit` will treat `\n` as a line separator.

Comment: Finally it worked for me with csvWriter.print("\r\n").@Neevek Thank you

Answer (score 2):

CSV files are not as easy to create as it may seem. I ran into a lot of issues when trying to write a quick CSV parser/writer.

Just use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and solve all your problems instantly.

Using OpenCSV you can do something like this:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
// feed in your array (or convert your data to an array)
String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
writer.writeNext(entries);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. try flush your stream before you close it
   `csvWriter.flush()`
2. instead using print, try println

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code (using [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)) - a thread-safe, mutable sequence of characters:

```
    public void writeData(String data, String strFilePath) {

    PrintWriter csvWriter;
    try {
        /*1. declare stringBuffer*/
        StringBuffer oneLineStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        File file = new File(strFilePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file = new File(strFilePath);

        }
        csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

        /*2. append to stringBuffer*/   
        oneLineStringBuffer.append(data + "," + "hello");
        oneLineStringBuffer.append("\n");
        oneLineStringBuffer.append("world");

        /*3. print to csvWriter*/
        csvWriter.print(oneLineStringBuffer);

        csvWriter.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change `csvWriter.print("world");` to `csvWriter.println("world");`. The next print going to be in next new line.

```
public void writeData(String data,String strFilePath)
            {

                PrintWriter csvWriter;
                try
                {

                    File file = new File(strFilePath);
                    if(!file.exists()){
                        file = new File(strFilePath);
                    }
                    csvWriter = new  PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));


                    csvWriter.println(data+","+"hello");
                    csvWriter.print("world");


                    csvWriter.close();


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```