# How to get the code display proper rows and columns in .csv format

Tags: java, csv, io, bufferedwriter, binaries

I have the following code. The problem is that its displaying back to back in columns.
Here is a picture from my excel file:
[image]

I want it to start over from next row once the record for single execution is filled from column to column.

Here is my code:

```
public class panel extends OrderSystem {

               final JTextField items;
               final JTextField number;
               final JTextField cost;
           final JTextField amount;




          public panel() {

              JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();    
                myFrame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

                myFrame.setTitle("GUI Demo - ISTE-121");
                myFrame.pack();
                myFrame.setLocation(600,300);
                myFrame.setSize(400,200);
                myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                myFrame.setVisible(true);

          JPanel order = new JPanel();
          order.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5,2,2));

          myFrame.add(order, BorderLayout.CENTER);

          order.add(new JLabel("Item no:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
          order.add(items = new JTextField(3));

          order.add(new JLabel("Number of:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
          order.add(number = new JTextField(3));

          order.add(new JLabel("Cost", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
          order.add(cost = new JTextField(3));

          order.add(new JLabel("Amount owed:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
          order.add(amount = new JTextField(10));
          amount.setEditable(false);


          JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
          buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,2,2));

      myFrame.add(buttons ,BorderLayout.CENTER);

          JButton calculate;
          buttons.add(calculate=new JButton("Calculate"));

          calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
          {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                double cost1 = new Double(cost.getText().trim()).doubleValue();
                double number1 = new Double(number.getText().trim()).doubleValue();

                double result =  cost1*number1;
                amount.setText(String.valueOf(result)); 

            }

          });

          JButton save;
          buttons.add(save = new JButton("Save"));

          save.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 



                try{

                        // Assume default encoding.
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("data.csv",true);
                        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);



                        bufferedWriter.newLine();
                        bufferedWriter.write(',');

                        bufferedWriter.write("\"ItemCode:\""+"\""+ items.getText() +"\""+",");
                        bufferedWriter.write("\"ItemNumber:\""+"\""+number.getText()+"\""+",");
                        bufferedWriter.write("\"ItemCost:\""+"\""+cost.getText()+"\""+",");
                        bufferedWriter.write("\"AmountOwned:\""+"\""+amount.getText()+"\""+",");
                        bufferedWriter.newLine();

                        bufferedWriter.close();


                }  

                    catch(IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println(
                            "Error writing to file '"
                            +  "'");
                        // Or we could just do this:
                        // ex.printStackTrace();
                    }





            }}  
            );



          JButton clear;
          buttons.add(clear=new JButton("Clear"));

          clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 items.setText(null);
                 number.setText(null);
                 cost.setText(null);
                 amount.setText(null);
            }});

          JButton exit;
          buttons.add(exit= new JButton("Exit"));

           exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
           {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          System.exit(0);

        }


           });



           JPanel buttons2 = new JPanel();
              buttons2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,2,2));

          myFrame.add(buttons2 ,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

              JButton load;
              buttons2.add(calculate=new JButton("Load"));

              calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
              {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub





                }

              });




                  JButton next;
                  buttons2.add(calculate=new JButton("Next>"));

                  calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                  {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub





                    }

                  });




                      JButton prev;
                      buttons2.add(calculate=new JButton("<Prev"));

                      calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                      {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub





                        }

                      });

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android: How to write newline in CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241999/android-how-to-write-newline-in-csv-file)

Here is written that you can use write.print("\r\n") so use to "\r\n" to make a new line

instead of writing

```
bufferedWriter.newLine();
```

you write

```
bufferedWriter.write("\r\n");
```

or

```
bufferedWriter.write("\r");
bufferedWriter.newLine();
```

since bufferedWriter.newLine(); only writes "\n" into your file as far as i know.
hope it will help you

Comment: Can u pls type in the full command code, where should I put write.print("\r\n")
@Gorock