# Return file in an object from spring rest controller

Tags: java, file, csv, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to create a rest controller which returns an object which contains a String, Long and a csv file. I am unable to do it because as soon I write the file creation logic in java, rather than returning it, it creates a file on my host.

I have already tried to write the entire object to the httpservletresponse using writer and output stream, but it did not give the expected result. I returned the object from controller, but instead of returning the object, it created a file on my host and did not return other values at all.

```
public class MyReturnObject {
  private Long countOfRows;

  private File csvDataFile;

  private String errorMessage;
}
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/fetchInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public MyReturnObject fetchInfoRestControllerMethod (String param1) {
//some logic/ service calls
return createMyReturnObject(values);
}
```

```
public MyReturnObject createMyReturnObject(List<CustomObject> values) {
  File csvFile = new File("myinfo.csv");
  file.createNewFile();
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);
  writer.write("test");
  //some lines
  MyReturnObject returnObject = MyReturnObject.builder()
                                .countOfRows(x)
                                .csvDataFile(csvFile)
                                .errorMessage(y).build();

  return returnObject;

}
```

This is just some dummy code I wrote. The object that I am building in `createMyReturnObject` is not returning the expected result. I am thinking if it is possible to return something like object `MyReturnObject` from a rest controller. Please help me with ideas to get expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot have two response [bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body) at the same time. You can have it either set to `text/csv` or to `text/json` and you can return a single response body at a time.

However, you can convert your CSV into bytes and `Base64.enocode` it and put inside of the object. You can also store your CSV in a string and return it with a custom [line separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242123/6252399).

Comment: I do not have a CSV already available, I need to create it in the code so I believe `Base64.encode` will not be the appropriate way to do it. Any idea how the string can be interpreted as csv file by the caller method which is java fetch call?

Comment: Okay, if you can't to make your file downloadable and return it as a json. However, you can return json object with csv inside one of the properties and on the frontend parse that property, create csv and send it to a client. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834261/6252399) is one of the examples

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your class MyReturnObject use a jackson library or gson in you project.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/fetchInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody MyReturnObject fetchInfoRestControllerMethod (String param1) {
    return MyReturnObject.builder()
                                .countOfRows(x)
                                .csvDataFile(csvFile)
                                .errorMessage(y).build();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand how can I retain csv file after the serialization of object and how can file be serialized.